# iOS disk space is not enough when i download some files in IOS

Tags: ios, crash

I have an app for download some files to the path of Cache. 
when the IOS disk space is not enough ,what will be happen? it can be crash!!!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should try that on your test device.